# Can I check if a variable is NULL within an Update's SET?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that uses a simple UPDATE with some variables passed to it. But I don't want to update those fields when their variables aren't null. This is essentially what my statement looks like.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = @myColumn,
    mColumn1 = @myColumn1
WHERE myColumn2 = @myColumn2
```

Is there anyway to apply some conditional logic within the SET? I have around 10 fields that need to be checked, so I wouldn't want to do an update per field or something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you can use a `CASE ... END` expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) is your friend. It returns its first non-NULL argument. I'm not actually sure from your narrative which way around you want things, it's either:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = COALESCE(myColumn,@myColumn),
    mColumn1 = COALESCE(myColumn1,@myColumn1)
WHERE myColumn2 = @myColumn2
```

Which keeps the current column's value if the column's not null, or

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = COALESCE(@myColumn,myColumn),
    mColumn1 = COALESCE(@myColumn1,myColumn1)
WHERE myColumn2 = @myColumn2
```

Which keeps the current column's value if the *variable* is null.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [coalesce](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms190349.aspx) function as below

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = coalesce(myColumn,@myColumn),
    mColumn1 = coalesce(mColumn1,@myColumn1)
WHERE myColumn2 = @myColumn2
```

Above code updates your columns only when they are null. If they are not null the code sets the same value stored in the columns.

Answer (score 1):

ISNULL ( variable , in case of null default value)

[INFO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)